# Node express app using cluster is not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application that is using node.js (express) as backend.
I am now trying to use node.js cluster to improve the application performance but with no luck...

Here's my working app.js :

```
import { Server } from "./server";
import { Debug } from "./utils/Debug";
const cluster = require("cluster");
const http = require("http");
const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
const httpPort = 3000;

 var app = Server.bootstrap().app;
 app.set("port", httpPort);
 var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
 httpServer.listen(httpPort);
```

And here is the code using cluster (which is not working) :

```
import { Server } from "./server";
import { Debug } from "./utils/Debug";
const cluster = require("cluster");
const http = require("http");
const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
const httpPort = 3000;

Debug.log(numCPUs + " CPU(s)!");
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // If a worker dies, log it to the console and start another worker.
  cluster.on("exit", function (worker, code, signal) {
    console.log("Worker " + worker.process.pid + " died.");
    cluster.fork();
  });
  cluster.on("online", function (worker) {
    console.log("Worker " + worker.process.pid + " is online");
  });

  // Log when a worker starts listening
  cluster.on("listening", function (worker, address) {
    console.log("Worker started with PID " + worker.process.pid + ".");
  });
} else {
  /**
   * Create HTTP server.
   */
  var app = Server.bootstrap().app;
  app.set("port", httpPort);
  var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  httpServer.listen(httpPort);
}
```

When I run the above my localhost:3000 is not listening.

What is wrong here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to let PM2 manage the cluster thing.
So I installed it and manage my application with it using a ecosystem.config.js file like this :

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "myApp",
      script: "./dist/app.js",
      instances: "max",
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      max_memory_restart: "300M",
      error_file: 'err.log',
      out_file: 'out.log',
      log_file: 'combined.log',
      time: true,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I hope this will help.